# Is this the right use of Bayes Law and approach for solving this problem?

Tags: probability

Problem:

There are $25$ skateboarders, $15$ basketball players, and $10$ volleyball players in training camp. They have to meet the requirements of qualification.
The probability that they will qualify is:

$0.9$ for skateboarder,

$0.8$ for basketball player,

$0.7$ for volleyball player.

Find the probability, that chosen athlete will qualify and that it will be done by volleyball player.

Solution:
It seems to me that the fact that I am asked for probability, that the athlete will qualify, knowing that it will be volleyball player, indicates that I have to use Bayes Law.  So,

Q-athlete will qualify

V-athlete chosen will be volleyball player

$$P(Q|V)=\frac{P(V|Q)\cdot P(Q)}{P(V)}$$
$$P(Q)=0.7$$
$$P(V)=\frac{10}{50}=0.2$$

So what would be $P(V|Q)$?
Is this the right approach?

Comment: By the wording of the question, you are not looking for the probability of qualifying given that the athlete plays volleyball, but qualifying AND being a volleyballplayer, i.e. $P(Q \cap V)$. If it were $P(Q \mid V)$, the answer would be just $0.7$ by the info you were given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A \cap B)=P(A \mid B)P(B)=P(B \mid A)P(A)$

Comment: So is $P(Q \cap V)=0.7 \cdot 0.2=0.14 $ correct?

Comment: @KristiansKuhta yes